# How to maintain user sessions in DropWizard?

Tags: session, dropwizard

I am looking for a persistent session manager which saves the session on file system (like PHP) that can be used with DropWizard. I see there is one `Environment.getSessionHandler()`, but I see no documentation on it.

I could write my own but I am hoping for a cooked meal. Will the above SessionHandler is what I am looking for? And how to use that?

Comment: if you got the solution , plz write it as answer

Answer (score 6):

With dropwizard>0.7

```
environment.jersey().register(HttpSessionProvider.class);
environment.servlets().setSessionHandler(new SessionHandler());
```

And then use `@Session` annotation in your resource classes.

Comment: @AppleGrew I was wondering if you guys have a provider gistand/or a few more gist to share. In my case I have to set and check a cookie value (it is a jwt token) that doesn't persits on server.

Answer (score 2):

DropWizard does not support sessions out of the box and based on posts by the author in google groups, they aren't planning on supporting it in the future either.

The only way currently would be for you to implement `org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler` yourself or look for something that already exists and then call `environment.setSessionHandler(...)`

And in case you need this info, DW 0.6.2 uses Jetty 8.1.10

You can also checkout http://cosmo-opticon.net/blog/2013/1/23/session-based-security-in-dropwizard and see if you can reuse some of that.

Comment: DW>0.8 now use Jersey 2 and injection framework has changed (HK2). This article is outdated, it needs adaptations for DW>0.8,

Answer (score -3):

REST is by definition stateless so no sessions should be used at all. The same URI should always return the same results regardless of the session state.