# Dropwizard View authentication by example

Tags: java, authentication, cookies, shiro, dropwizard

I'm familiar with implementing `BasicAuth` security in Dropwizard, but only for RESTful endpoints/resources.

I am now experimenting with Dropwizard Views to see if I can use it to be both a web and REST server all in one. The web app will have "public" pages (that are really just static HTML files; "About Us", "Contact Us", etc.) as well as "private" (dynamic) pages, which really form the app. To get to these pages the user must be authenticated (logged in).

So this means I have the need for two distinct DW authentication mechanisms:

- A typical DW security mechanism for authenticating REST API clients, which I'm familiar with; and
- A way to implement a log in system for authenticating end users for the web app pages/resources

Ideally, I'd like Apache Shiro to handle all auth for my system (REST and web alike), and I see the [Dropwizard-Shiro](https://github.com/silb/dropwizard-shiro) lib, but that seems to only authenticate REST endpoints.

---

My web login system need to work like so:

1. A user tries to go to an "authenticated" (private) URL.
2. A servlet filter (that I create myself and register with the `environment`) intercepts the request and can tell (perhaps a cookie/session var?) whether the user is authenticated or not.
3. If the user is authenticated, they are allowed to proceed to their intended URL ("*target URL*"). Otherwise they are redirected to a login page. When they login a DW resource/controller hands their credentials off to Shiro, who then decides whether the credentials are valid or not.
4. If the credentials are valid, they get a cookie/session var (?) and are redirected to their target URL. Otherwise they are redirected back to the login page which will now display a failure message.

My main concerns are:
* **What should I implement for the cookie/session var that the servlet will check for?**; and
* **How do I integrate my auth controller (that is, the resource that handles redirection between the login page and the target URL) with Shiro?** Is it possible to do this via that Dropwizard-Shiro lib?

#### My best attempt thus far:

**Custom Servlet Filter (registered with `environment`):**

```
public class AuthFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, 
            ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
        Cookie[] cookies = requestContext.getCookies();
        boolean authenticated = false;
        for(Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            // 1. This is my first concern. What is better/more secure
            //    than what I'm doing here?
            if("my_app_auth_cookie".equals(cookie.getName())) {
                authenticated = true;
            }
        }

        if(authenticated == false) {
            responseContext.sendDirect("/auth/login");
        }
    }
}
```

If they are not authenticated they redirect to `/auth/login` which hits a `AuthController` (again, registered with the `environment` as a resource):

```
@Path("/auth")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public class AuthController {
    @GET
    @Path("/login")
    public LoginPageView login() {
        // Render some "login.ftl" template as HTML.
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/authenticate")
    public ??? authenticate(??? username, ??? password) {
        // 2. Somehow send 'username' and 'password' to Shiro...
        MyAppUser user = myAppRealm.authenticate(username, password);

        // Now what do I do with 'user'?
    }
}
```

When the user submits the form on the login page (which might be a POST to `/auth/authenticate`) we somehow hand their inputted credentials off to Shiro (again I'd like to use that Dropwizard-Shiro lib since I will likely also be using it for my REST endpoints).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Shiro has its own type of [filters](http://shiro.apache.org/web.html#Web-defaultfilters) which are configured in `shiro.ini`.

Example:

```
[urls]
/api/** = noSessionCreation, authcBasic
/views/login = authc
/views/authenticated = authc, user
```

Configure the `authc` filter to redirect to a login form page that you implement. Use the filter's [form parameters](http://shiro.apache.org/web.html#Web-FormbasedLogin) and POST to `/views/login`.

If you enable the session manager in Jetty, Shiro should create servlet sessions when they log in from the login form page.

Please note that I haven't actually tested this configuration.

Comment: Thank you so much @silb (+1) - just a few quick followups for you (regarding servlet sessions) if you don't mind: **(1)** Can you confirm that [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27211249/4009451) is the right way to "enable the session manager" from inside a DW app? And **(2)** the only thing that worries me about enabling sessions for the views (web pages) is that it might mess things up with my REST endpoints, since REST is supposed to be stateless. Thoughts? Thanks again!

Comment: NM for #1 above, I see the note in the Dropwizard-Shiro README about enabling sessions. Still *mildly* concerned about #2 though...