# How to maintain users sessions in DropWizard 1.0.x

Tags: session, dropwizard

The correct way to configure and (de)reference HttpSessions in DropWizard 1.0.x is not documented. How is it done?

Versions 0.7.x and 0.8.x are covered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19970591/how-to-maintain-user-sessions-in-dropwizard), but it seems like things have changed as some of the classes referenced are not part of 1.0.x afaict.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the line with the class that isn't available, or Spring Boot.

<s>`environment.jersey().register(HttpSessionProvider.class);`</s>
`environment.servlets().setSessionHandler(new SessionHandler());`

Then, for instance:

```
@GET
@Path("/email")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response getSessionEmail(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    return Response.ok(request.getSession().getAttribute("email")).build();
}
```

Comment: SessionHandler is non-trivial to implement

Comment: `new SessionHandler()` ?

Comment: As I recall it (over a year later) there was a long chain of components to marshal before i would get the behaviour I wanted, i.e. something that will work in a cluster. I am not thinking of SessionHandler alone. I don't recall any more about it than that. Sorry.

Comment: Either sticky sessions or a JDBCSessionManager would deal with that trivially.

Answer (score -2):

Forget it, use Spring Boot.

Spring has a heritage of front end technologies to preserve and is a better fit for anything that naturally requires a session.

Comment: Why the negativity? Using another, more suitable technology is surely a sensible option?